# Android Listview gravity center of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to know how to adjust my listview **activity_main_menu_listview** in center of LinearLayout. I tried with gravity but its not work for me but when I give it margin so it worked. But i want it auto, so how can i do it?
Thanks

```
<com.entropy.slidingmenu2.layout.MainLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <!-- This holds our menu -->
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- This holds our content-->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- This acts as Actionbar -->
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_btn"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_button_menu" />



    </LinearLayout>       

    <!-- This is where fragment will show up -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainLayout Code:

```
public class MainLayout extends LinearLayout {

// Duration of sliding animation, in miliseconds
private static final int SLIDING_DURATION = 500;

// Query Scroller every 16 miliseconds
private static final int QUERY_INTERVAL = 16;

// MainLayout width
int mainLayoutWidth;

// Sliding menu
private View menu;

// Main content
private View content;

// menu does not occupy some right space
// This should be updated correctly later in onMeasure
private static int menuRightMargin = 120;

// The state of menu
private enum MenuState {
    HIDING,
    HIDDEN,
    SHOWING,
    SHOWN,
};

// content will be layouted based on this X offset
// Normally, contentXOffset = menu.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth - menuRightMargin
private int contentXOffset;

// menu is hidden initially
private MenuState currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;

// Scroller is used to facilitate animation
private Scroller menuScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
        new EaseInInterpolator());

// Used to query Scroller about scrolling position
// Note: The 3rd paramter to startScroll is the distance
private Runnable menuRunnable = new MenuRunnable();
private Handler menuHandler = new Handler();

// Previous touch position
int prevX = 0;

// Is user dragging the content
boolean isDragging = false;

// Used to facilitate ACTION_UP 
int lastDiffX = 0;

// Constructor

// 3 parameters constructor seems to be unavailable in 2.3
/*
public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
*/

public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MainLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

// Overriding LinearLayout core methods

// Ask all children to measure themselves and compute the measurement of this
// layout based on the children
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    mainLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    menuRightMargin = mainLayoutWidth * 30 / 100;
    // Nothing to do, since we only care about how to layout
}

// This is called when MainLayout is attached to window
// At this point it has a Surface and will start drawing. 
// Note that this function is guaranteed to be called before onDraw
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    // Get our 2 child View
    menu = this.getChildAt(0);
    content = this.getChildAt(1);   

    // Attach View.OnTouchListener
    content.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return MainLayout.this.onContentTouch(v, event);
        }
    });

    // Initially hide the menu
    menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

// Called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to each of its children
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    //Log.d("MainLayout.java onLayout()", "left " + left + " top " + top + " right " + right + " bottom " + bottom);
    //Log.d("MainLayout.java onLayout()", "getHeight " + this.getHeight() + " getWidth " + this.getWidth());

    // True if MainLayout 's size and position has changed
    // If true, calculate child views size
    if(changed) {
        // Note: LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out

        //Log.d("MainLayout.java onLayout()", "changed " + changed);

        // content View occupies the full height and width
        LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = (LayoutParams)content.getLayoutParams();
        contentLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
        contentLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth();

        // menu View occupies the full height, but certain width
        LayoutParams menuLayoutParams = (LayoutParams)menu.getLayoutParams();
        menuLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
        menuLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth() - menuRightMargin;  
    }

    // Layout the child views    
    menu.layout(left, top, right - menuRightMargin, bottom);
    content.layout(left + contentXOffset, top, right + contentXOffset, bottom);

}

// Custom methods for MainLayout

// Used to show/hide menu accordingly
public void toggleMenu() {
    // Do nothing if sliding is in progress
    if(currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
        return;

    switch(currentMenuState) {
    case HIDDEN:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        menuScroller.startScroll(0, 0, menu.getLayoutParams().width,
                0, SLIDING_DURATION);
        break;
    case SHOWN:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
        menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 
                0, SLIDING_DURATION);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    // Begin querying
    menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);

    // Invalite this whole MainLayout, causing onLayout() to be called
    this.invalidate();
}

// Query Scroller
protected class MenuRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isScrolling = menuScroller.computeScrollOffset();
        adjustContentPosition(isScrolling);
    }
}

// Adjust content View position to match sliding animation
private void adjustContentPosition(boolean isScrolling) {
    int scrollerXOffset = menuScroller.getCurrX();

    //Log.d("MainLayout.java adjustContentPosition()", "scrollerOffset " + scrollerOffset);

    // Translate content View accordingly
    content.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerXOffset - contentXOffset);

    contentXOffset = scrollerXOffset;

    // Invalite this whole MainLayout, causing onLayout() to be called
    this.invalidate();

    // Check if animation is in progress
    if (isScrolling)
        menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
    else
        this.onMenuSlidingComplete();
}

// Called when sliding is complete
private void onMenuSlidingComplete() {
    switch (currentMenuState) {
    case SHOWING:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWN;
        break;
    case HIDING:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
        menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
}

// Make scrolling more natural. Move more quickly at the end
// See the formula here http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/22/the-making-of-prixing-fly-in-app-menu-part-1/
protected class EaseInInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float t) {
        return (float)Math.pow(t-1, 5) + 1;
    }

}

// Is menu completely shown
public boolean isMenuShown() {
    return currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWN;
}

// Handle touch event on content View
public boolean onContentTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // Do nothing if sliding is in progress
    if(currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
        return false;

    // getRawX returns X touch point corresponding to screen
    // getX sometimes returns screen X, sometimes returns content View X
    int curX = (int)event.getRawX();
    int diffX = 0;

    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Down x " + curX);

        prevX = curX;
        return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Move x " + curX);

        // Set menu to Visible when user start dragging the content View
        if(!isDragging) {
            isDragging = true;
            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // How far we have moved since the last position
        diffX = curX - prevX;

        // Prevent user from dragging beyond border
        if(contentXOffset + diffX <= 0) {
            // Don't allow dragging beyond left border
            // Use diffX will make content cross the border, so only translate by -contentXOffset
            diffX = -contentXOffset;
        } else if(contentXOffset + diffX > mainLayoutWidth - menuRightMargin) {
            // Don't allow dragging beyond menu width
            diffX = mainLayoutWidth - menuRightMargin - contentXOffset;
        }

        // Translate content View accordingly
        content.offsetLeftAndRight(diffX);

        contentXOffset += diffX;

        // Invalite this whole MainLayout, causing onLayout() to be called
        this.invalidate();

        prevX = curX;
        lastDiffX = diffX;
        return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up x " + curX);

        Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up lastDiffX " + lastDiffX);

        // Start scrolling
        // Remember that when content has a chance to cross left border, lastDiffX is set to 0
        if(lastDiffX > 0) {
            // User wants to show menu
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;

            // No need to set to Visible, because we have set to Visible in ACTION_MOVE
            //menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up contentXOffset " + contentXOffset);

            // Start scrolling from contentXOffset
            menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, menu.getLayoutParams().width - contentXOffset,
                    0, SLIDING_DURATION);
        } else if(lastDiffX < 0) {
            // User wants to hide menu
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
            menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 
                    0, SLIDING_DURATION);
        }

        // Begin querying
        menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);

        // Invalite this whole MainLayout, causing onLayout() to be called
        this.invalidate();

        // Done dragging
        isDragging = false;
        prevX = 0;
        lastDiffX = 0;
        return true;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: show output image. and desired image...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center an item, don't use a LinearLayout as these are meant for displaying a number of items in a row.

Use a RelativeLayout instead with property `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

```
<!-- This holds our menu -->
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
     >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

And make sure your `listview's` item layout also have `central` gravity.

I noticed you also used a custom `view` : `com.entropy.slidingmenu2.layout.MainLayout`

If its not working, please post both of those code.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply. Its working but in vertically not horizontally. :( I am posting my MainLayout code.

Comment: @user3555472 so `center` is working, but `center_horizontal` is not?

Comment: can't you go with Relative ?? @user3555472

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems going on.

1. Your parent LinearLayout is layout_width="wrap_content", which means that it only goes as far from the left edge of the screen as it needs to, not all the way to the right edge of the screen, which is what you want.
2. You need to tell your child ListView (activity_main_menu_listview) to center itself horizontally. The attribute you need is layout_gravity, not gravity. The layout_gravity attribute is for child views to say where within its parent it wants to be. The gravity attribute says where within the view itself (usually a TextView) the contents (usually the text) should go.

So what you need is this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, a couple of very minor points: 1) Google wants us to use match_parent instead of fill_parent (one of the stupidest deprecations in history); 2) You only need the xmlns attribute in the root view of the XML, not your ListView's parent.